# C++ srand() reset in function call

Tags: c++, algorithm, srand

I am currently working on code that generates random numbers on a 4 by 4 board. I have a board.h, board.cpp and a main.cpp file. In main.cpp I include `Board.h`.

In `Board.cpp` is where I construct the board using `rand();`. In `main` I create two instances of the class where I get the two boards

My issue is that if I use `srand((unsigned int)time(NULL))` in main I'll generate the same two different boards. Whereas if I use `srand((unsigned int)time(NULL))` in `Board.cpp` I get two identical boards. One solution I've found is sleeping for a second, but I am losing a lot of time by doing that and wanted to know if there's a better solution.

Comment: Use [better random number generators than `rand()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random)?

Comment: You need to do one single `srand` at program startup. Don't do more than one, and you'll get different boards.

Comment: You seem to have already found the solution – call `srand` only once. What's wrong with that solution?

Comment: Handy reading: [srand() — why call it only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once)

Comment: @molbdnilo I just tried it again and it worked! It seemed I had been calling srand() a second time and didn't notice.

Comment: @zeltath You created two boards, and each board called `srand`.

Comment: *"It seemed I had been calling srand() a second time and didn't notice."* Maybe it's time to post a [mre], if the dupe mentioned in the comments doesn't answer your question.